Equivalent forms Qual Problem
I have very little background with equivalent forms and am having trouble even finding a definition for this. The definition I have found is that two forms $f, g$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent if and only if there exists $M\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $$f(x_1, x_2)=g\bigg( M \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}\bigg)$$.
First of all, is this correct, and is there a more general definition I should know? (For the record, I have Googled this)
Secondly, I have the following old qualifying exam problem I am studying: Let $V=\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that the forms $x_1x_2$ and $2x_1^2-2x_2^2$ on $V$ are equivalent.
Here's the proposed solution I have right now:
\begin{align*}
f(x_1, x_2)&= 2x_1^2-2x_2^2\\
&=2(x_1-x_2)(x_1+x_2)\\
&=g(2x_1-2x_2, x_1+x_2)\\
&=g\bigg(\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -2 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}\bigg).
\end{align*}
Is it really this simple, or am I missing something?

Seems fine to me.
